# Implementing a trait for all types implementing a trait with const parameter

Tags: generics, rust, traits, const-generics

I believe that the following code makes sense:

```rust
trait FooConst<const N: usize> {}
trait Foo {}

impl<T: FooConst<N>, const N: usize> Foo for T {}
```

However when I try to compile it I get error E0207 stating that the parameter `N` is unbounded. I don't understand why, since it seems to me that it's part of the bound on `T`.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6cf65f88961052a34e778f4c2c698763)

Comment: It is because you don't bound `T` by N.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fundamental reason why this is not allowed is because the trait bounds may cause multiple trait implementations for the same type.

For example, consider a type `Bar` that implements both `FooConst<1>` and `FooConst<2>`, which is perfectly fine:

```rust
struct Bar;

impl FooConst<1> for Bar {}
impl FooConst<2> for Bar {}
```

If `Foo` is implemented for all `T: FooConst<N>`, then we get *two* `Foo` implementations for `Bar`: one for `N == 1` and one for `N == 2`. Rust does not allow the possibility of having multiple trait implementations, which is why it disallows using type parameters in this way.

One way to work around this is to instead make `N` an associated constant:

```rust
trait FooConst {
    const N: usize;
}
trait Foo {}

impl<T: FooConst> Foo for T {
    // T::N is an associated constant   
}
```

Comment: You're right, I wasn't thinking about the possibility that a type might implement the trait for multiple `N`. Actually now that I'm looking into it, it sounds like associated constants might be more appropriate for my use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I do not exactly know why this works while your code does not work, but here's a code that does what you want :

```rust
trait FooConst<const N: usize> {}
trait Foo {}

impl<const N: usize> Foo for dyn FooConst<N> {}
```

Feel free leaving a comment if you know why this works.

Comment: I think it's because `dyn FooConst<N>` cannot implement `FooConst<M>` for any other `M`, so the problem in the other answer is not an issue.